# How to make a type-guard for a branded type

Tags: typescript

Here is what I have

```js
    type Brand<K, T> = K & { __brand: T };

    type USD = Brand<number, 'USD'>;
    type EUR = Brand<number, 'EUR'>;

    const convertToEURO = (value: USD | EUR): EUR => {
        if (isUSD(value)) {
            return (value * 1.2) as EUR;
        }
        return value;
    };

    function isUSD(currency: USD | EUR): currency is USD {
        return '__brand' in currency; // && currency.__brand === 'USD';
    }

    test('Branded number', () => {
        let usd = 5 as USD;
        let eur = 10 as EUR;

        // fails - cool!
        // usd = eur;
        expect(usd).toBe(5);

        expect(eur).toBe(10);

        expect(convertToEURO(usd)).toBe(6);
        expect(convertToEURO(eur)).toBe(10);

        // Compiler shows error because "5" is neither EUR or USD
        expect(convertToEURO(5)).toBe(10);
    });
```

If I run this test I get `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '__brand' in 5`
Which is clear why but how else can I test if value is USD or EUR???

Comment: Branded types are just type system artifacts that help you from confusing two otherwise identical types at design time.  They have no effect at runtime, so you can't make a type guard that acts on them.  If the type you were branding were not a primitive, you could actually add properties to them for real (and then you wouldn't have a branded type, just an interface or something) and test at runtime.  If you find yourself really caring about runtime, make an interface like `interface Currency { value: number; type: string }` and then deal with those.

Comment: Thats what I feared but I hoped for a fancy solution though - Thanks. You want to copy your comment into an answer so that I confirm it?